# Where did the Google calendar widget go?

Tags: google, calendar, app-widgets, weather

Until recently, I had the combined date / weather widget from Google on my home screen. Clicking on it opened either the calendar, or the weather frog app.

A few days ago, I noticed it was replaced with the Google assistant 'quick overview' widget, and I can't find the original one in the list of widgets.

Did Google remove that widget altogether, or is there a way to get it back?

I did get an update to Android 13 recently, but I'm not sure if that's related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Google removed the combined date and weather widget from Android 13. The widget was replaced with the Google Assistant Quick Overview widget.

There are a few ways to get the combined date and weather widget back:

- Use a third-party launcher such as Nova Launcher or Lawnchair
  Launcher. These launchers allow you to add widgets that are not
  included in the stock Android launcher.
- Use a third-party weather app such as Pixel Weather Widget & Themes.
  These apps typically have their own widgets that you can add to your
  home screen.
- Use a custom widget pack. There are many custom widget packs
  available on the Google Play Store. Some of these widget packs
  include a combined date and weather widget.

To add a widget using a third-party launcher, long-press on an empty space on your home screen and select "Widgets". Then, select the widget from the list of widgets.

To add a widget using a third-party weather app, open the app and go to the settings menu. Then, look for a section labeled "Widgets" or "Home screen widgets". Select the widget that you want to add to your home screen.

To add a widget using a custom widget pack, open the app and select the widget that you want to add to your home screen. Then, follow the instructions that are provided by the app.

I hope this helps!